# Xamarin.Forms - How to Implement Gesture Recognizers in iOS for Gestures Other than Tap?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipe, gesture, pan

In Xamarin.Forms, apparently a tap gesture is the only cross-platform gesture. So how do I implement other gesture recognizers (example swipe and pan) for iOS?

Comment: Look at the Mr.Gestures nuget package, it adds support for a lot of gestures on iOS and Android.

Comment: Dependency Injection + Native Implementations of gesture recognizers

Answer (score 1):

This post could be helpful for you

http://blog.twintechs.com/cross-platform-compositional-gesture-advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-4

Also the TwinTechsFormsLib has swipe and pan gestures implemented

https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib/tree/master/TwinTechsForms

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented up/down/left/right gestures on an image in Xamarin Forms that works in iOS/Android/Windows UWP.. Take look here: http://alan.beech.me.uk/blog/xamarin-forms-detect-swipe